# Trouble drawing an ellipse around two elements of a forest environment

Tags: color, diagrams, nodes, forest, trees

I have seen some questions about the same topic in the forum, but I've been unable to reproduce the same output in my code, so I would start by saying sorry for posting similar questions but here we go...

I have the following code as of now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={draw, circle, inner sep=2pt,minimum width=1cm,
            font=\small, s sep=1cm}
        [u
            [u.e]
            [u.d, name = ud
                [
                    [w,edge = dotted, name = w]
                    [,draw=none,edge = dotted]]
                    [,draw=none,edge=dotted]]
            ]
            \node[draw,blue,circle,fit = {(ud) (w)}]{};
    \end{forest}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

As an extra, is there a way to make my dotted edges a little darker? I feel like I can barely notice them. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You need `\usepackage{forest}`, which automatically loads `tikz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ellipse, and then rotate and scale it to your needs. To thicken the dots, use `edge = {thick,dotted}`

[image]

```
                [w,edge = {thick,dotted}, name = w]
                [,draw=none,edge = {thick,dotted}]]
                [,draw=none,edge={thick,dotted}]]
        ]
        \node[draw,blue,ellipse,rotate=145, xscale=.4, fit = {(ud) (w)}]{};
```